# Java or Scala Map using Tuples as Key and providing Views ot Iterators for Partial Keys?

Tags: java, scala, collections, tuples, scala-collections

Is there a Map that takes a tuple as Key and provides methods to get views ([as in Guava's Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#views)) to "fix" one part of the key and get a Map that just takes the other part of the key?

This map should provide some methods like:

```
val ages = MagicMap[(String, String), Int]()
ages += ("Albert", "Einstein") -> 138
ages += ("Albert", "Schweitzer") -> 142
ages += ("Hermann", "Einstein") -> 170

val alberts: Map[String, Int] = ages.view1("Albert") // Map("Einstein" -> 138, "Schweitzer" -> 142)
val einsteins: Map[String, Int] = ages.view2("Einstein") // Map("Albert" -> 138, "Hermann" -> 170)
```

Due to performance, it is necessary to iterate over the submaps (i.e. `alberts` and `einsteins`), without iterating over the whole key set of the original map (`ages`). So, `filter` or `groupBy` do not help.

Also, using nested Maps (`Map[String, Map[String, Int]]`) is not possible, because they allow only filtering by one part of the key and not by the other.

Although immutable Maps would be okay, the most preferrable solution would be a mutable map that provides fully functional views, such that `einsteins += "Eduard" -> 107` results in `ages` having one more entry `("Eduard", "Einstein") -> 107`.

Comment: I think you need two Maps.